# Please explain these equations relating to Newtonian gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Here is an extract from some badly-written slides:

- A planet in an orbit with radius $R$ having a period $T$ falls through a distance of $R$ in a time $T/4$.
- A planet has a speed of $R/T$ and an acceleration of $R/T^2$.
- Comparing gravity on Earth $g$ with the moon $g_m$ at a distance $R_m=4\times10^8m$: $g/g_m=9.81T^2/(16R_m)\approx10^4$.
- Compare this with $(R_e/R_m)^2\approx5\times10^3$.
- Newtown abandoned the inverse square law for a time because this test failed. The problem was the incorrect value for $R_m$.

Can someone please explain where $T/4$ comes from in the first line, how the formula in the third line is constructed, and what the comparison is supposed to show?

What is the person who wrote these slides actually trying to say?

Comment: The first two bullets miss some $\propto$ symbols or factors of $\pi$. Third bullet: $g/g_m$ should be dimensionless, but has dimension $[s^2/m]$. What is $R_e$ supposed to be?

Comment: $R_e$ I assume is the radius of the Earth, but the slides don't explain themselves any further than this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the workings of the mind of an unknown person.

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): Consider providing a link to the slides.

Comment: I think this would be more easily answered by asking the author of the slides what they meant. If they are unavailable, you may as well learn from different slides or books, websites, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reference to a calculation Newton did in Proposition IV of Book III of the Principia. It's known as the *Moon test*. Googling *Newton moon test* or something like that will find you lots of articles.

Suppose the Moon were halted in its orbit, then the distance it would fall in a time $t$ is shown in the following diagram as AC:

[image: Moon]

where Newton showed that the distance $AC$ is related to the distance the Moon would have travelled round its orbit, $AB$, by:

$$ AB^2 = AC \times AD $$

The distance $AD$ is just twice the orbital radius, $2r_m$, and if the period is $T$ then the distance $AB$ is:

$$ AB = 2\pi r_m \frac{t}{T} $$

And substituting for $AB$ and $AD$ gives:

$$ AC = \frac{2\pi r_m}{T^2} t^2 $$

and since $s = \tfrac{1}{2}at^2$ that gives the acceleration due to the Earth's gravity at the radius of the Moon as:

$$ g_m = \frac{4\pi r_m}{T^2} $$

Give or take a factor of $4\pi$ that's the expression in the second bullet point.

The point of all this is that the radius of the Earth, $r_e$, was well known in Newton's day, and of course the acceleration at the Earth's surface, $g_e$, is easy to measure, so if the inverse law applies we should have:

$$ \frac{g_e}{g_m} = \frac{g_eT^2}{4\pi r_m} \approx \frac{g_eT^2}{16 r_m} $$

if you make the approximation that $4\pi = 16$, though why you'd make this approximation isn't obvious. This is the equation in the third bullet point.

Presumably it was an error in $r_m$ that led to this not being the case, and that's why Newton doubted the inverse square law. I can't comment further because i've never studied that bit of the history of science.

Comment: Why the downvote? What I've written can be verified by just Googling Newton's moon test. There's nothing controversial about it.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one imo. I am going to delete mine, because I did not get that $R_m$ is the *orbital* radius of Moon. A quick number check would have revealed that mistake.